# How to iterate multiple times until get expected response text in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have used below code inside while controller but not working. Any one help me on that please
${__javaScript("${textcheck1}".indexOf("Message") == -1
&& !(("${textcheck2}".indexOf("Message1") == -1),))}

Thanks,
Yazhu

Answer (score 0):

It's "not working" due to a syntax error which is because of unbalanced parentheses.

The valid syntax would be something like:

```
${__javaScript("${textcheck1}".indexOf("Message") == -1 && !(("${textcheck2}".indexOf("Message1") == -1)),)}
```

however I'm not sure that it will "work" as well because I don't know what you're trying to achieve.

Going forward I would recommend creating functions using [The Functions Helper Dialog](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#function_helper) and looking at [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) if anything is "not working" first.

Also as per [__javaScript() function documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__javaScript)

> javaScript is not the best scripting language for performances in JMeter. If your plan requires a high number of threads it is advised to use __jexl3 or __groovy functions.

Check out [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article for more information on Groovy scripting in JMeter.

Comment: My script should be iterate multiple times until get the expected "text" from response body.